# Random partitioning of single-mode thermal light

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistics

While studying Fundamentals of Photonics by Saleh and Teich, I find it difficult to prove that the photon-number distribution of randomly partitioned single-mode thermal light retain its Bose-Einstein form.

A random sampling being modelized as a lossless beamsplitter of transmittance T, the probability of obtaining m photons at the output when thermal light is injected can be written as :
\begin{equation*}
P(m)=\sum_{n=m}^{+\infty}\binom{n}{m}T^m(1-T)^{n-m}\frac{(\bar{n})^n}{(\bar{n}+1)^{n+1}}
\end{equation*}

where $\bar{n}$ is the mean photon-number of the incoming beam.

I know that the outcome is supposed to be also a thermal light distribution of mean $T\bar{n}$, but the actual calculation gives me a hard time, especially I don't see how to get rid of the binomial coefficient (whereas in the Poissonnian case, the factorials disappear really naturally).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after some more thorough investigation, I found an elegant way to show this in [Electromagnetic Noise and Quantum Optical Measurements](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540652724) by Haus, chapter 9, paragraph "Statistics of Attenuation".

The key is to work out the probability-generating function of the partitioned photon stream and then compare it to the original probability-generating function.

Starting with a stream which has a probability distribution $p_0(n)$, the probability-generating function of the sampled photon stream is then :

\begin{equation}
G(\xi)=\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}p(m)\xi^m=\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}p(m|n)p_0(n)\xi^m =\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}p_0(n)\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}p(m|n)\xi^m
\end{equation}

Using the fact that $p(m|n)=0$ if m>n (the output cannot have more photons than the input) and is binomial otherwise, we get :

\begin{equation}
G(\xi)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}p_0(n)\sum_{m=0}^{n}\binom{n}{m}T^m(1-T)^{n-m}\xi^m
\end{equation}

which yields the general result :

\begin{equation}
G(\xi)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}p_0(n)(1+T(\xi-1))^n
\end{equation}

In the case of an initial Bose-Einstein distribution of mean $\bar{n}$ : $p_0(n)=\frac{1}{\bar{n}+1}(\frac{\bar{n}}{\bar{n}+1})^n$, we get the result :

\begin{equation}
G(\xi)=\frac{1}{1-T\bar{n}(\xi-1)}
\end{equation}

which is the probability-generating function of a Bose-Einstein distribution of mean $T\bar{n}$.

I am very satisfied with this method, however I am still wondering if this was the "easy way" that was expected from the book's authors. Any comments are welcome.